# How do I make flask redirect("abc") return relative to the url path the app is running on?

Tags: python, flask

I have my flask app running on `domain.com/test/` .  In my code, I'd like a redirect to return a user to domain.com/test/login if they hit any URL in the app (route handler or not) and are not logged in.

If I do `redirect("/abc")`, it sends them to `domain.com/abc`.  If I do `redirect("abc")`, and they come from a route such as `domain.com/test/bla/` , it sends them to `domain.com/test/bla/abc`.

I would just like the redirect to send them to `[url-flask-app-is-running-on]/[the-redirect-path-segment]`

On another note - can I give redirect an endpoint instead of a string path?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. you can use `return redirect('domain.com/test/login')` which is a full path.
2. if your code is like:

```
@app.route('/test/login')
def login_form()
     pass # login form
```

then you can use `return redirect(flask.url_for('login_form')`

source of redirect: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors

source of url_for: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#url-building

Answer (score 0):

Any value that would normally work for a HTML link should work in redirects as well.